# mysql query for multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql for survey answers.
the schema of the survey table is as follows:

`id  | rating1 | rating2 | rating3 | rating4 | .... | rating20 |
  1      10        10       2          8       ....       4 
  2       8         8       8          5       ....       7`
 
As you can see, there's rating scores (from 1 to 10) inserted into rating1 - rating20 fields.
I can easily find biggest or smallest scores from rating(1-20) fields for each row using this query: "SELECT greatest(rating1, rating2 ..  rating20) FROM TBL_SURVEY WHERE id=1" which returns 10 for id 1. 
But I don't know that greatest score belongs which field. And I like to count distnct rating scores. How many 10s or any other scores from rating1-rating20 fields for id 1? 
Is there mysql queries for this? or Is there a way to get what I want using php?

Any help would be very appreciated...

Comment: Thanks Alex, then what is the better database schema for this kind of work? I'd welcome any suggestions.

Comment: @user1942626 Most database functions are designed to operate on _records_ (rows), not columns.  MySQL's `GREATEST()` function is leading you down the wrong path.  Get your data into normalized records and your problem becomes much easier.

Comment: Tim, I accept your kind advice. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you change your table design to something like this:

```
id | rating_id | rating
1  | 1         | 10
1  | 2         | 10
1  | 3         | 2
1  | 4         | 8
etc.
```

With this improved and normalized design, we can find the max rating and its corresponding `rating_id` using a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ratings t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, MAX(rating) AS max_rating
    FROM ratings
    GROUP BY id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id AND
       t1.rating = t2.max_rating
```

For your second question of e.g. how many 10s there are for `id` 1 we could use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ratings
WHERE id = 1 AND rating = 10
```

Comment: Thanks Tim,  but with this table structure,  a lot of records will be created.